# "Flight recorder" for automobiles/motorcycles?

Tags: memory, tracking, tracklog

As I sat in traffic court last week for a non-moving violation, many of the cases were clearly he said/she said issues.. particularly with stop sign violations.   I can easily see how this specific problem could be a source of abuse by both police and citizens.

Case in point - I stop at all stop signs.  I usually count to 2 before moving, but because of the location of the white line, It may look like I never really stopped to someone coming along the cross street.

Are there any **court-admissible** devices that will accurately (and *affordably*) record vehicle movement, location, and perhaps speed?

Comment: I don't think this question is suited to this particular community. You might have better luck in an automobile engineering forum.

Comment: My auto GPS captures movement (speed) and location.   There may be a GPS device on the market now that does exactly what my post asks for.  If this is not the best community for GPS related questions, I apologize.

Comment: Judging on these results: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps  It appears this is would be the correct location for this question, and the downvote was unnecessary.

Comment: This site covers only one aspect of your question:  GPS units.  The fact that your question specifically addresses the question of automobiles and court-admissibility makes it a specialized question that you're unlikely to get an answer to here.  Without any research to back it up, I would imagine that there are no commercially available GPS units that would be admissible in court for this purpose, as they all tend to not be as precise as would be necessary for this situation (the detection of NO movement)

Comment: No problem -- I do see that it was upvoted twice, and favorited as well.  Some gis exachange members felt it was relevant.  Nevertheless, I understand wanting to keep things strictly on topic.